# Matlab Struct array with indexing to python

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert MATLAB code into Python.
The MATLAB code that I am try to convert resembles the code below:

```
for i=1:10
 country.car(i).x(1) =150;
 country.car(i).x(2)=300;
end
```

This gives an output

```
country.car(1).x=[150,300]
```

In Python, I had tried this  :

```
country={}
country["car"]={}
country["car"]["x"]={}
```

but I am not able to index the variable `x`. so I am stuck at this point

I would be glad if you can provide other methods/ examples which help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eventually use a nested dictionary containing a list:

```
country = {'car': {'x': [150,300]}}
```

And now you can get the information with:

```
country['car']['x'][0]
...
```

Or with multiple `car`:

```
country = {'car': [{'x': [150,300]},{'x': [100,200]}]}
```

And you can get the information with:

```
country['car'][0]['x'][0]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like following snippet:

```
#n is the number of cars
car = [dict() for i in range(n)]
#0 implies first car; 0-based indexing
car[0]["x"] = [150, 300]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Doesn't the above method work if I require struct as follows country.car(1).x=[150,300]

Comment: In MATLAB, you are assigning the `car(1).x` to a list of values, right? Structs are usually, for some constant properties, whose value is assigned in the new objects that you create.

Comment: I have corrected my question above please have a look

Comment: One clarification, `{}` is dictionary in python, unless you use it as a set, but it does not imply struct. Also, when you try this: `country["car"]={}`, it means that there is single "property" car in the country dictionary. Do you want multiple cars?